# Define dynamic setter using method_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to be able to use in my code the following construct:

```
p obj.graph_XYZ
obj.graph_XYZ << obj2
```

Here I want to handle any getter/setter beginning with `graph_`

I can hook onto the getters, but method_missing picks the getter even when I use `obj.graph_XYZ << obj2`. Any inputs as to what i may be doing wrong?

Comment: `<<` is no setter, so depending on what you bind to `XYZ`, the receiver will be different. A setter would look like `graph_XYZ=`.

Comment: Right, i also tried catching `graph_XYZ=` in method_missing, but this is not called when using `<<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you?

> ```
> $ irb                                                                                      
>
> class A
>   attr_accessor :xyz
> end
> => nil
> a = A.new
> => #<A:0x0000010096bc88>
> a.xyz
> => nil
> a.xyz << 2
> NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
>   from (irb):6
>   from /Users/iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
> a.xyz = [ ]
> => []
> a.xyz << 2
> => [2]
> a.xyz
> => [2]
> class A
>   def method_missing( name, *args )
>     return super( name, *args ) unless name.to_s =~ /^graph/  
>     words = name.to_s.split( "_" )
>     words.shift # get rid of graph_
>
>     # now do what you like
>     # ...
>     if (instance_variable_get "@#{words.first.downcase}").nil?
>       instance_variable_set "@#{words.first.downcase}", []
>     end
>
>     (instance_variable_get "@#{words.first.downcase}")
>   end
> end
> => nil
> a = A.new
> => #<A:0x00000100844a58>
> a.graph_XYZ
> => []
> a.graph_XYZ << 2
> => [2]
> a.graph_XYZ
> => [2]
> ```

Comment: Thing is, in my case the attribute is not set locally, but is set using the rest API on neo4J, any ideas what can be done in that case?

Comment: I don't know neo4J, but the one thing you have to manage is initialising the variable with an array. You could do that by calling the getter first, and if it's nil pass `[ ] << obj2` to `graph_XYZ=`. It adds overhead but without knowing the database API it's all I can suggest.